# jQuery focus not working on input

Tags: jquery

Want to trigger the focus event on new loaded text input field, but it is not working.
Have tried following

```
setTimeout(function() { jQuery("#element").focus() }, 3000);
jQuery("#element").focus();
document.getElementById('element').click();
jQuery("#element").trigger("click");
```

Comment: have it inside document ready?

Comment: @guradio yes it is inside document ready.

Comment: Add your HTML and a sample snippet if possible to reproduce the issue, This will help the community to give a solution quicker

Comment: Add your html code so that we can see what was the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't given us the full context of what's going on in your page.  Like, when are you calling this code and such.  However, I think your issue may be related to trying to invoke the focus event before the control has been rendered on the page.  Therefore, there are 2 things you can try to resolve the issue.

1. Ensure that your code block isn't running before the page has finished loading (see example A)
2. Call your code after the control you want to use it on has loaded (example B)

Example A:

```
$(function() {
   jQuery("#element").focus();
});
```

Example B:

```
$("#element").load(function() {
    $(this).focus();
});
```

Comment: jQuery code was calling before the new elements added to DOM.